# The script added inside the multiline text field is getting deleted by itself in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sitecore-client

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA 1.7. I have created a Multiline text field and it has a script inside it. The script inside is getting deleted by itself after some time.
Any solution for this and the reason behind it?

[image]

Except "lang:en_US " other scripts will get deleted by itself.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using @Html.Raw() in view? ANd i think SXA has Html component too that could help.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for a Sitecore RichText field is to strip out all script tags from the markup.

This setting controls the behavior:

```
<setting name="HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts" value="true" />
```

If you want to enable script tags, you would need to change that setting.

Comment: The field type which i used here is multiline and i tried with rich text also  but same thing happened in rich text too.Can you please share the file name where can i find this setting.@Richard Seal

Comment: its within the sitecore.config file

Comment: if i make it false , will this gets changed to default value(true) when SXA upgrade takes place? @Jean Nicolas G

Comment: yes. always use patch file when playing around default config